# Taking Honor Mechanics class in college this semester and It would be great to get your opinions on advanced textbooks compatible with such a class?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I used to like and think that Halliday and Resnick was the best, but I've heard it is not really advanced. What honors physics textbook would you recommend or is the one most used out there?

Again, I'm looking for a very specific type of book, which is an advanced one for honors physics classes in college. A huge list of all possible physics books is definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) and links therein

Comment: Not a duplicate in my opinion

Comment: Eddie, I put that link because it contains links to various questions about mechanics books. Figured it would be better to let you know about all of them and not just one specific link there.

Comment: "College" is a term with different meanings in different places.  It's commonly used in my part of the world to mean third level (e.g. university) and also for second level (what is called "high school" in some places).  However the people you really need to ask this are the people running the course.

Answer (score -1):

i learned physics via Halliday & Resnick in 1971. The concepts covered in it have not become irrelevant since then. If you wish to study physics more advanced than this, you still need to work your way through W&S first.

Comment: What is W&S????

Comment: oh sorry, it is Weidner & Sells, another classic physics book, it's actually on the same level as halliday & resnick.

Comment: Mind posting an Amazon link? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have one, sorry.